# Objective C: Determining the coordinates of a 'click'

Tags: objective-c, animation, uiimageview, coordinates

I'm trying to make a UIImageView loaded with an array for an animation appear on top of a button when it is clicked. The location of the buttons is random so I have no way of initializing the UIImageView with a frame. How do I pass in the X and Y coordinates of where the user taps on the screen?

Comment: What is receiving the event, the button? What coordinate space do you want the click event's coordinate to be in, the window's, the button's, or some other view's?

Comment: The receiving event is the button, I need the coordinates of the button (preferably the center of it), but the animation will appear in the window's view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you hook up the IBAction for the UIButton, it is passed the button object itself when it is called.  The UIButton's frame property should give you everything you need.

Also, you don't "click" on iOS, you "tap".

Comment: ... or you 'touch'.  As in 'TouchUpInside'.  =)

Comment: Actually, iOS supports three different types of actions: action, action:(id)sender, and action:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event. The last two types provide the button as 'sender', and the last also provides the event as 'event'.